# WorksheetFunction.SumIfs based on Range that has date and time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a SumIfs that sums all the values in a range based on a date like this

```
Dim v_date as Date
v_date = Date
result = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("C3:C100"),Range("A3:A100"),v_date)
```

The problem is that Range("A3:A100") has date and time in it but i want to filter only by date.
I tried adding a wildcard like `v_date & "*"` but it didn't work. The result is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming v_date is a date only it will default to midnight.  Therefore you need to filter by `>=v_date` (midnight) and `<v_date+1` (midnight next day)

```
result = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("C3:C100"), _
Range("A3:A100"), ">=" & CDbl(v_date), _
Range("A3:A100"), "<" & CDbl(v_date + 1))
```

Comment: The result is still 0

Comment: How have you declared v_date?  If it is a variant then this might not work.  If it is a date then change the code as edited above.

Comment: Yes, it is declared as date, and with your updated answer it works. Thanks!